# "1215 - cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql

I have to create a double foreign key in the "Sceglie" table, but MySQL shows me always the same error: "#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint ". It only happens with "Cognome_candidato" and not with "Nome_candidato".I've also tried to write `FOREIGN KEY (Nome_candidato, Cognome_candidato) REFERENCES Candidato(Nome_candidato, Cognome_candidato) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`, but it didn't create the double foreign key. How can i solve it?

```
create table Candidato (
Nome_candidato varchar(255),
Cognome_candidato varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Nome_candidato, Cognome_candidato));

create table Sceglie (
Email varchar(255),
Nome_candidato varchar(255),
Cognome_candidato varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Email, Nome_candidato, Cognome_candidato),
FOREIGN KEY (Email) REFERENCES Utente(Email)
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
FOREIGN KEY (Nome_candidato) REFERENCES Candidato(Nome_candidato)
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
FOREIGN KEY (Cognome_candidato) REFERENCES Candidato(Cognome_candidato)
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an index for cognome_candidato, before a foreign key can reference that column.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Candidato`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Candidato` (
  `Nome_candidato` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Cognome_candidato` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Nome_candidato`, `Cognome_candidato`))
  ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Utente`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Utente` (
  `Email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Email`))
  ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Sceglie`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Sceglie` (
  `Nome_candidato` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Cognome_candidato` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Nome_candidato`, `Cognome_candidato`, `Email`),
  INDEX `fk_Candidato_has_Utente_Utente1_idx` (`Email` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Candidato_has_Utente_Candidato_idx` (`Nome_candidato` ASC, `Cognome_candidato` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Candidato_has_Utente_Candidato`
  FOREIGN KEY (`Nome_candidato` , `Cognome_candidato`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`Candidato` (`Nome_candidato` , `Cognome_candidato`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Candidato_has_Utente_Utente1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`Email`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`Utente` (`Email`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: The code that you have posted hasn't created the table, but i tried to use indexes anyway, and then it worked. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have tested the code on both linux and windows and it works. The reason it does not work for you is likely due to a different database name. Just try changing the "mydb" with your database name and it should work.

Comment: Sorry, i just forget it, i'm new in this community and i still learning all this kind of rules. Thank you.